# Having Problems In Uploading Files To Target Folder

Tags: php, upload

I am new to PHP and still learning it... Today I can not figure out why the files are uploaded out of the targeted directory - $target_dir.. I changed the $target_dir many times but I always get the same results.. The code looks fine to me..

Any idea?

Thank you..

```
 function avatarUpload(){

    $target_dir = "../uploads/avatars/";
    $target_file = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["avatar"])) 
    {

        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) 
        {
            //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else  {
           // echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) 
    {
        do
        {
            $rand = rand(100,10000);
            $target_file = $rand .= $target_file;
        } 
        while( file_exists($target_file) );
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000000) 
    {
        //echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;

    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;

    } else {

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)== true) 
        {

           // echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
           return $target_file;

        } else 
        {
           // echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";

           return $target_file;

        }
    }


    return $target_file;
    }
```

Comment: what is uploaded out ?

Comment: Everything is okay, just the folder is missed.. I am getting the files to the root..

Comment: check your path, try changing it to absolute and then run. `../` seems to create issue

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to append target directory to file name.

```
$target_file = $target_dir .basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Comment: if your queries are resolved would you mind accepting the answer. This will help future readers with similar issue getting resolved